# difference between disapproval with and disapproval of

Tags: meaning

I read an article in news papers and i noticed that the author used the word  disapproval with the preposition with but as far as I know this word takes "of" as a preposition

Comment: *Disapproval **of*** is more common than *disapproval **with***, but they both occur and are idiomatic; the "with" form has a more arch or distancing tone. Having said that, for whatever reason you can't say "approval with" to mean "approval of". Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, at least in U.S. English, you "disapprove of" but can "have disapproval with ( or of)."
Examples:

> I disapprove of your actions toward your family.
>
> I have already expressed my disapproval with your actions toward your family. So, I'll try to remain quite on the subject from now on.

However, you could also use "disapproval of" in the last sentence.